# Executing one Java program from another using Runtime.exec(...)

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

The tester program that I wanted execute takes in a single argument -- a filename -- and makes a copy of the file with the line "This is a modified version." at the top of the new file. When I tested this program alone, it works and produces a new file.

Then I wrote the program to call the file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("java Tester.java inputfilename.txt");
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The program above printed out "Done" but it never made a modified version of the file I passed in. I then put some println()'s in the other program. When I run that program alone, it printed out those statements, but when I tried to call it from the program above, it did not. How do I fix this?

Comment: Jari told you why it did not work in general. But concerning the output: You explicitly have to *read* the output that is generated by the program that you start there. Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21904185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compile `.java` file first and launch it later:

Compile (class containing the main method):

```
javac Tester.java
```

Launch:

```
java Tester inputfilename.txt
```

Comment: I added (before the line:Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("java Tester.java inputfilename.txt");) the line: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Tester.java"); and then ran the program. It still didn't work. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Open `cmd`, run this stuff manually and tell me what errors you get.

Comment: The message I got: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Tester/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tester.java
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: Well, that a different question, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334148/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror or just google for it.

Comment: `.NoClassDefFoundError: Tester/java` indicates you are **still** adding the `.java` extension when using the `java` command!  Jari advised you around an hour before that, to *remove* it!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I figured that out yesterday and ran the program without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
"java Tester.java inputfilename.txt"
```

Should be:

```
"java Tester inputfilename.txt"
```

But do yourself a favor and read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

That might solve other problems.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason for failure.

Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.