# How to access linux command such as sed,awk from java

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have been studying JNI (Java Native Interface) since last month.It is really interesting .I mean call Java functions from C and vice versa.Now I have an intention call linux command which I mentioned above like sed,awk from Java side.also I have a little bit knowledge about Sell Script in linux. please give me some hint how to do this.

Comment: ProcessBuilder, Runtime.exec() etc

Comment: Running separate binaries (as opposed to library functions) doesn't require the JNI.

Answer (score 1):

You should Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder depending on what you require to execute process into your local system.

This questsions could help:

- [difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)
- [Java Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595748/java-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this java snippet to run a shell command:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo This is a test"); //Start the process
process.waitFor(); //Wait for the process to terminate
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); //Get the output
```